# Why can't "unless" mean "except if" in "My wife will be angry unless I'm home by 7.00"

Tags: unless

A Practical English Grammar reads:

> **Unless** means 'except if', so it's not used when the meaning is more
> like 'because ... not’:
>
> *My wife will be angry if I'm not home by 7.00*
>
> **※** *My wife will be angry unless I get home by 7.00*
> (She will be angry because I’m not home.)

I still can't see why *unless* can't mean "except if" here.

**UNLESS**: https://oed.com/oed2/00268144

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/453471/where-does-negation-go-with-if-vs-unless

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where does negation go with "if" vs "unless"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/453471/where-does-negation-go-with-if-vs-unless)

Comment: It would appear [the question has already been asked](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/66100/my-wife-will-be-angry-unless-im-home-by-7-00), [more than once](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/30642/if-not-vs-unless), and [outside SE](https://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/topic/unless-and-if-not). You should also fully reference your quotation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is answered on a sister site: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/66100/my-wife-will-be-angry-unless-im-home-by-7-00

Comment: The second of the three links in Andrew Leach's comment seems to be the best. The allegedly wrong "My wife will be angry unless I get home by 7:00" is perfectly grammatical and means the same as the other sentence. Both are common explanations (or excuses) for my leaving the party at 6:30.

Answer (score 2):

There is no significant difference in meaning between the two, so I wouldn't worry over it. I'm not sure what the "X" is on the second sentence, but both are grammatically correct and commonly used.

If there is a difference in meaning, it's very subtle. There's a similar question on another Stack Exchange and the general consensus is this:

> My wife will be angry if I'm not home by 7.00.

This implies that my wife is not angry. However, if I get home after 7:00, she will become angry. Arriving after 7:00 will trigger my wife's anger.

> My wife will be angry unless I get home by 7.00.

Here, "unless" means "except if". The sentence implies that my wife will be angry even if nothing else happens. But, if I'm home by 7:00, I might be able to prevent her anger.

The difference is so subtle that it would almost never be noticed during a spoken conversation.

Comment: https://oed.com/oed2/00268144

Comment: **Except** is defined as _"**If not** for (the fact that)"_  and **unless** as _**Except** on the condition that_ https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=except

Comment: What meaning of will are you using in your second sentence form these ones?  https://www.wordreference.com/definition/will